# Django python View and Form - MultiValueDictKeyError at /result 'num1' - Why will my form not submit data

Tags: python, html, json, django, forms

I've created a form to add two numbers and receive MultiValueDictKeyError at /result
'num1'.  I've tried many things but can't figure it out.  I figured I'd give this a try.

@project -> url.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path, include
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    from datetime import datetime

    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('', include('app1.urls')),
        path('result', include('app1.urls')),
    ]

    urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

@App-> url.py:

```
    from django.urls import path, include
    from django.conf.urls import include, url
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    from . import views
    from . import urls
    from app1.models import Footprint
    import app1.views


    urlpatterns = [

        path("", views.index, name="index"),
        path('result', views.calc, name='result'),
    ]
```

@App -> views.py:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.http import HttpRequest,HttpResponseRedirect
    from .models import Footprint

    # Create your views here.
    def index(request):
        foots = Footprint.objects.all()         
        return render(request, "index.html", {'foots': foots})

    def calc(request):
        val1 = int(request.POST['num1'])
        val2 = int(request.POST['num2'])
        res = val1 + val2
        return render(request,'result.html',{'result': res})
```

@templates -> index.html file where i write my form:

```
    {% block content %}
    <form action="calc" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p style="color:white;">Installation Cost:</p> <input type="text" name="num1">
        <p style="color:white;">Installation Year:</p> <input type="text" name="num2"><br><br>
        <p><a href="result" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-custom">SUBMIT</a></p>

    </form>
    {% endblock %}
```

@result.html:

```
    {% block content %}
    Result: {{result}}
    {% endblock %}
```

@here i got error

```
    MultiValueDictKeyError at /result
    'num1'
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/result
    Django Version: 3.0.3
    Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
    Exception Value:    
    'num1'
    Exception Location: C:\Users\scott\Envs\venv\lib\site-                        
    packages\django\utils\datastructures.py in __getitem__, line 78
    Python Executable:  C:\Users\scott\Envs\venv\Scripts\python.exe
    Python Version: 3.8.0
    Python Path:    
    ['C:\\Users\\scott\\projects\\marciano',
     'C:\\Users\\scott\\Envs\\venv\\Scripts\\python38.zip',
     'C:\\Users\\scott\\Envs\\venv\\DLLs',
     'C:\\Users\\scott\\Envs\\venv\\lib',
     'C:\\Users\\scott\\Envs\\venv\\Scripts',
     'c:\\users\\scott\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\Lib',
     'c:\\users\\scott\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\DLLs',
     'C:\\Users\\scott\\Envs\\venv',
     'C:\\Users\\scott\\Envs\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
     Server time:   Fri, 14 Feb 2020 21:33:42 -0500



    Environment:

    Request Method: GET
    Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/result

    Django Version: 3.0.3
    Python Version: 3.8.0
    Installed Applications:
    ['app1',
     'django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles']
    Installed Middleware:
    ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



    Traceback (most recent call last):File "C:\Users\scott\Envs\venv\lib\site-    packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 76, in __getitem__
    list_ = super().__getitem__(key)

    During handling of the above exception ('num1'), another exception occurred:
      File "C:\Users\scott\Envs\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
      File "C:\Users\scott\Envs\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
      File "C:\Users\scott\Envs\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\scott\projects\marciano\app1\views.py", line 14, in calc
    val1 = int(request.POST['num1'])
      File "C:\Users\scott\Envs\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 78, in __getitem__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)

    Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError at /result
    Exception Value: 'num1'
```

Comment: Please share the entire error message.

Comment: just added it to the end of the post.

Answer (score 0):

In your code templates -> index.html file where you write a form specify action change `calc` to `result`  and also remove `a` and `href` and add the `<button type='submit'>submit</button>`

@index.html

```
{% block content %}
    <form action="result" method="post"> #here change the action 
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p style="color:white;">Installation Cost:</p> <input type="text" name="num1">
        <p style="color:white;">Installation Year:</p> <input type="text" name="num2"><br><br>
        <p><button type='submit' class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-custom">SUBMIT</button></p>
 # here  above you change the remove a and href='result' it reference and add submit button for submit the data
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

@apps -> url.py

```
path('result', views.calc, name='result'),  #here you name your url is result
```

> because you name your url result also best practice to remove hard code remove url use that {% url %} template tag

and use the get function in your view where you get the `num1` and `num2`

@views -> views.py

```
def calc(request):
        val1 = int(request.POST.get('num1 ',1)) # here use the get method of dictionary see in python docs
        val2 = int(request.POST.get('num2',1)) # also same change use get method num2 is key and 1 is default value 
        res = val1 + val2
        return render(request,'result.html',{'result': res})
```

> [`get()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-method-dictionaries-python/)method is give a value of key if method not found any key it will return default value here we pass 1 if we not pass default value it take `None`

Here you make change in your code and if it work make a right answer for this question eventually let me know this work or not

Comment: First, thank you for the comments.  Second, this kinda of works.  Now it is just adding up the two default values from num1 and num2.  So the result is always 2.  Also, i tried using the template tag and it just kept bring me back to the homepage when I would submit the form.  I'm probably using it incorrectly.  Thank you again for your help!

Comment: First, thank you for the comments.  Second, this kind of works.  Now it is just adding up the two default values from num1 and num2.  So the result is always 2.  Also, i tried using the template tag and it just kept bring me back to the homepage when I would submit the form.  I'm probably using it incorrectly.  Thank you again for your help!

Comment: @feather i update my answer let check it work or not you also forgot the add submit button in your form not 'anchor tag'  a and href='result' remove it follow get request and you not submit the data it redirect you if it work or not let me know

Comment: You are a wizard! That fixed it.  Thank you so much!

Comment: can you accept the answer is right of your question in stack please